# Wired networking stops responding when wireless is connected. 12.04 Server

Tags: wireless, networking, server

I have a strange problem win an Ubuntu Server 12.04 box.  I've just added a wireless card to the box, and configured it.  The wireless is working fine but the wired connection stops responding.

If I disable the new wirless (`ifdown wlan0`) then the old `eth0` immediately starts responding.  If I bring the wireless back up (`ifup wlan0`) then the old `eth0` stops responding.

To be clear of what I mean by "stops responding"; I can not find any indication on the server that eth0 is being disabled, just any attempt to contact that IP (including a ping) will fail.

The wireless is on a separate subset to the wired this is for routing reasons. The wireless is on 192.168.10.X and the wired is on 192.168.20.X

My `/etc/network/interfaces` file

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
    wpa-ssid Somewhere Over The Rainbow
    wpa-psk foo bar

iface eth0 inet dhcp
    post-up /sbin/ethtool -s eth0 wol g
```

The result if `ifconfig`

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:01:2e:2d:64:03  
          inet addr:192.168.20.46  Bcast:192.168.20.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::201:2eff:fe2d:6403/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2504 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1616 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:263710 (263.7 KB)  TX bytes:146295 (146.2 KB)
          Interrupt:16 Base address:0x6c00 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:300 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:300 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:32604 (32.6 KB)  TX bytes:32604 (32.6 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 1c:4b:d6:c3:2b:53  
          inet addr:192.168.10.14  Bcast:192.168.10.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::1e4b:d6ff:fec3:2b53/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:962 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:806 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:100025 (100.0 KB)  TX bytes:104869 (104.8 KB)
```

Can anyone see why this wont let both interfaces work at the same time, and how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Given that they're on separate subnets, this is probably a routing issue.  It sounds like packets that should go out directly on eth0 to the 192.168.20.0/24 subnet are instead going to the default gateway on (presumably) 192.168.10.x, which then doesn't understand how to route them.

Also, I need clarification: are you saying that **other machines on the LAN** can no longer successfully ping the server, or are you saying that **the server** can no longer ping other machines on the LAN?

Comment: Hmmm detecting this is going to be interesting, I'll have to look up a good packet sniffer.  I've been testing this as other machines being unable to ping the server.