# Debug WOL failing to configure on Ubuntu Server 12.04

Tags: 12.04, server, wakeonlan

I have a PC running Ubuntu Server 12.04.  I'm having trouble getting this to wake on LAN (WoL).  I'm now pretty certain I've narrowed this down to an issue with Ubuntu or the way it's configured.

The reason I say this is that if I boot the box from an Ubuntu Desktop 12.04 install disk, go into "try now" and then shut down the machine will wake on lan.

According to this link: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WakeOnLan - the command `sudo ethtool eth0` should show `Wake-on: g` if the card is set up to wake on lan and only require `ethtool -s eth0 wol g` if this shows the `d` flag.  It does not show the d flag and does show the same on both the ubuntu desktop install disk and the server.  I have however tried both with and without this command being fired on the server when the network comes up and neither works.

I dont really know how to go about debugging this and figuring out why it's not working.  I dont see anything in the syslog which looks useful (but I wouldn't know what to look for) and the only point at which it becomes evident that WoL is not working is when the machine is switched off!

How can I go about debugging why Ubuntu Server 12.04 is not correctly enabling WoL?  What else can I look for that is different between the desktop install disk and my installed server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies for answering my own question.

This appears to have been a mistake in my `/etc/netowork/interfaces` file.  The file was referencing an old wireless card I'd had to take out due to [problems I was having with the card](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217096/wired-networking-stops-responding-when-wireless-is-connected-12-04-server).

I'm guessing that something was incorrect in the `/etc/network/interfaces` file.  I had split the 
`auto eth0` and the `iface eth0 inet dhcp...` either side of the config for the wireless card by mistake.

Either way I removed the wireless config as this was no longer doing anything and WoL started to work just fine.